# Error Undefined offset: 5 in multiple insert Laravel 6

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to make a restaurant ordering system where the waiter can put more than 1 order in the food menu,

I tried to make multiple inserts, but there was an error like this

`Undefined offset: 5`

My Controller looks like this:

```
foreach ($request->menu_id as $item) {
    $data_item = array('menu_id' => $request->menu_id[$item],
        'order_id'=>$request->order_id[$item],
        'qty'=>$request->qty[$item],
        'subtotal'=>0 );
     Order_detail::insert($data_item);
```

My view like this

```
<div class="panel panel-headline" id="keterangan">
    <form action="{{url('pelayan/order/detailorder')}}" method="POST" autocomplete="off" id="form-detail">
        @csrf
        <div class="panel-heading" id="judul-keterangan">

        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="panel-body" id="detailorder">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="menu_id">Choose Your Food</label>
                <select class="form-control text-uppercase menu_id" name="menu_id[]">
                    <option>Choose Your Food</option>
                    @foreach($menu as $m)
                        <option value="{{$m->id}}">{{$m->name}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
                <input type="text" name="qty[]" class="form-control qty" placeholder="Silahkan Masukkan Jumlah Menu">
             </div>
            <div id="tambahorder">

            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="tambah">Tambah Pesanan</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="simpanorder">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I can't insert how to insert multiple rows in Laravel.

Comment: 'order_id'=>$request->order_id[$item] ,check your request value include order_id

Comment: As checked, you don't have an "order_id" field passed along your request. And also, when you get error like "Undefined offset", it's because one of the input fields related to that index (in your case, it's 5) is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($request->menu_id as $item) {
    $data_item[] = [
        'menu_id' => $request->menu_id[$item] ?? 0,
        'order_id' => $request->order_id[$item] ?? 0,
        'qty' => $request->qty[$item] ?? 0,
        'subtotal' => 0
    ];
}

Order_detail::insert($data_item);
```

Answer (score 1):

it look likes you use **foreach($arr as $value)**
so **$item** is value, not key..
and if value is greater than the key, the offside is undefined..

example :

- your menu id is 1,2,3,4,5,6
- your qty is 5
- so if you select id 5, this code **$request->qty[$item]** means **$request->qty[5]**
- it will print error Undefined offset: 5 because your qty only [0,1,2,3,4]

maybe you can try **foreach($arr as $key => $value)** and change **$request->qty[$item]** to key, not value.

or you can use a variable start from 0, and use it as increment..

EDIT :

**where are your order_id??**